# Jquery using Second word rather than first word

Tags: jquery, split, trim

Using jQueryListnav to display a nice alphabetical list on a page, works fine apart from that the client now wants it to search by last name and not first e.g.

Tom Jones - it currently orders by Tom and not Jones

https://github.com/esteinborn/jquery-listnav/blob/master/jquery-listnav.js

Where / how would I amend this script to do that?

**Edit**
fixed by using Solfiene's answer and a little Js to wrap the surname in a span:

```
$("#element").each(function(){
 var $this = $(this), text=$this.text().trim(), words = text.split(/\s+/);
 var lastWord = words.pop();
 words.push("<span class=\'last-word\'>" + lastWord + "</span>");
 $this.html(words.join(" "));
});
```

Thanks

Comment: can't you change your printed names? instead of [first name - last name], can you print [last name - firsrt name]?

Comment: No, not without some clever php / jquery as the names are printed from the db, but @sofiene has given me an idea on how to accomplish this.

Comment: If the names are "printed from the db" (implying a single 'name' field) then how will you separate the last-name as suggested in the Sofiene's answer?

Comment: wrapping the last name in a span using jQuery.......:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this using the option `filterSelector` you can specify a css selector for your navigation to filter by last name.

**Javascript**

```
$('#list').listnav({
    filterSelector: '.last-name',
});
```

**HTML**

```
<ul id="list">
  <li>Tom Jones<span classs="last-name" style="display: none;">Jones</span></li>
</ul>
```

[ListNav Documentation](http://ericsteinborn.com/jquery-listnav/#tabpage_6)